# Devolver valor JSon en C#

Tags: c#, json, mvc

Buenos días/tardes/noches SOes,

Hace ya varios días que estoy intentando realizar una sentencia y no puedo dar con la tecla.

*El tema es el siguiente*:

Tengo que agregarle a un Contrato dependiendo cual sea, una letra delante: "A" o "B", estoy utlizando MVC. Tengo mi método en el controlador el cual recibe como parametro un Tipo, ID, año y mes.

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult Cto(string Tipo, int IdProveedor, int Anio, int Mes)
{
switch (Tipo) {

case "A":
return new JsonResult() { Data = servicio.GetContratoA(Id, Anio, Mes).ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };

case "B":
return new JsonResult() { Data = servicio.GetContratoB(Id, Anio, Mes).ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
            }
 }
```

Ahora bien, este método JSon es llamado por mi Vista Index con una función AJAX.

```
function LoadCto(tipo) {
```

Los datos me los trae perfectamente, la cuestión es: 
**¿Cómo le agrego adelante de estos contratos la letra que deseo(ya sea A o B)?**

**SALIDA OBTENIDA:**

```
CONTRATO 1
```

**SALIDA DESEADA (cto tipo A)**

```
A CONTRATO 1
```

**SALIDA DESEADA (cto tipo B)**

```
B CONTRATO 5
```

**TIP:** no lo puedo agregar en la funcion GetContrato llamada de servicio porque me produce un problema de Entity ya que se usa en varias instancias este método.

Comment: Data = servicio.GetContratoA(Id, Anio, Mes).ToList() , deberia devolverte una lista. ?

Comment: @LucianoMontañez Así es. una lista con todos los contratos y con su modificación de A o B

Answer (score 0):

Prueba hacer lo siguiente:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult Cto(string Tipo, int IdProveedor, int Anio, int Mes)
{
    switch (Tipo) 
    {

        case "A":
            var a = "A";
            return Json(new { letter = a, Data = servicio.GetContratoB(Id, Anio, Mes).ToList(), , JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet });
        case "B":
            var b = "B";
            return Json(new { letter = b, Data = servicio.GetContratoB(Id, Anio, Mes).ToList(), , JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet });
    }
}
```

declaras una variable dentro del `case` donde guardes la letra en este caso **A** o **B** luego la envías como `json` hacia el `view`.

Otra forma seria declarar la variable fuera del `switch` y dentro de cada `case` solo llenarla con el dato que corresponda.

Answer (score 0):

Otra opción podría ser que devuelvas un tipo complejo que tenga dentro tu lista y el tipo. algo así.

```
public class TuTipo{
    string Tipo { get; set; }
    List TuLista{ get; set; }
}

[HttpGet]
public JsonResult Cto(string Tipo, int IdProveedor, int Anio, int Mes)
{
    var dataResult = new TuTipo() { Tipo = Tipo };

    switch (Tipo) {
    case "A":
        dataResult.TuLista = servicio.GetContratoA(Id, Anio, Mes).ToList();
    case "B":
        dataResult.TuLista = servicio.GetContratoB(Id, Anio, Mes).ToList();
            }
return new JsonResult() { Data = dataResult, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
     }
```

Por otro lado como recomendación, podrías considerar hacer el tipo un enum y no tener código en duro.

No probé este código pero espero que se entienda, en caso de cualquier duda quedo atento.

Answer (score 0):

Te agrego como yo lo haria, un poco similar a la de **@manu_rit**, pero con algunos cambios.

```
public class ContratoCollection
{
    [JsonProperty("tipo")]
    public string Tipo { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("contrato")]
    public Contrato Contrato { get; set; }

    public ContratoCollection() { }
}

[HttpGet]
public object Cto(string Tipo, int IdProveedor, int Anio, int Mes)
{
    ContratoCollection cc = new ContratoCollection() { Tipo = Tipo};

    switch (Tipo)
    {
        case "A":
            cc.Contrato = servicio.GetContratoA(Id, Anio, Mes).ToList();
            break;
        case "B":
            cc.Contrato = servicio.GetContratoB(Id, Anio, Mes).ToList();
            break;
    }

    var obj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cc);

    return obj;
}
```

Para utilizar el **`JsonConvert.SerializeObject`** asegúrate que todos los objetos tienen un **`constructor`** vació.